Seeking Assistance with Custom Hardware Interface for ros2_control
I am working on developing a custom hardware interface for ros2_control and would appreciate guidance or a working example that I can modify to fit my needs. I decided to try using ros2_control_demos, but encountered issues.
When I build and run the demo from the repository, it works without any errors:
cd ~/ros2_ws
vcs import src < src/ros2_control_demos/ros2_control_demos.humble.repos
rosdep update --rosdistro humble
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y --rosdistro humble
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.sh
colcon build --symlink-install

However, if I simply clone the example into my workspace, I start facing issues with the spawner.
Here’s what I did:
Built the workspace from the repository.
Deleted the source code of the example, as well as the build and install directories.
Cloned the example source code back into my workspace.
I am not including the logs here because I believe the issue lies in my understanding of how to adapt the example for my needs. These errors prevent me from successfully creating a custom hardware interface plugin.
I am seeking help from the community to:

Identify what I might be missing in adapting the ros2_control_demos examples.(I’m really at a loss here. I expected the basic example to be more adaptable.)
Suggest a reliable and validated example that likely wouldn't have these issues.

Here is the structure of my directories:

Thank you for your assistance!

What are the errors then? I see from your screenshots that you have two times example_2. You cannot have two equally names examples in your workspace.

The error was in
[spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available.
If you look closely, you’ll see that there are no duplicate example_2 entries in my workspace.
The issue was with one of the ROS 2 packages. It caused some of the rosdistro dependencies to not update correctly. A complete reinstallation of rosdistro, including deleting the configuration files, resolved the problem.
